# TypeError: jQuery(...).iosSlider is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, jquery-slider

Link: [www.dev.pt.to](http://dev.pt.to)

Error on product sliders bellow:

```
TypeError: jQuery(...).iosSlider is not a function    ...onLastSlideComplete:function(){jQuery('.new-arrow.next').addClass('disabled');},...    dev.len...ulos.pt (linha 108, col 417)

TypeError: jQuery(...).iosSlider is not a function    ...nLastSlideComplete:function(){jQuery('.sale-arrow.next').addClass('disabled');},...    dev.len...ulos.pt (linha 116, col 423)

TypeError: jQuery(...).iosSlider is not a function    ...true,infiniteSlider:true,autoSlide:true,autoSlideTimer:1500});jQuery('.shop-news...    dev.len...ulos.pt (linha 91, col 205)

TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null    overlay.js (linha 7333, col 4)
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null    overlay.js (linha 7333, col 4)
```

I can't understand what's causing this and why slider do not work properly. :(

I haven't changed anything at all regarding jquery, so it should work with no problems.

I have already replaced jquery.slider.js with original and still the same error.

Can't understand why this is happening. :(

Comment: why would you even consider using frames in 2014? They are deprecated in html5  http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html and sure make JS troubleshooting a chore

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about, I just implemented the theme and this error appeared. :P Can you help me a little bit to understand what you mean?

Comment: look at page source of link you provided, is using frames which are obsolete

Comment: All I can see are divs and more divs, I see no frames in there. :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I don't know what they did, but the guys from the theme I bought just solved the problem for me. :)

Comment: can you please share the solution ?

Comment: I would really like to help, but just as I said, I have no idea because this was corrected by the theme support guys. :( Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You may have changed the order of your script tags. Be sure that the slider plugin is loaded first before your code.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your kind help. Yes it's loading first and even so, no effect whatsoever. :( Any other idea of what it can be?

Comment: Please, can you help me here? :(